# Time taken to iterate through a table vs. table size SQL

Tags: sql, loops

I have a SQL table I will need to iterate through.  However, I expect this table to grow after my site is launched.  How does the size of a table affect the time it takes for SQL to iterate through it?

Comment: Do you mean literally iterate, as in using a cursor? While it's largely linear, please tag your DBMS, as these treat cursors differently.

Answer (score 1):

If your query has to do a table scan, increase in size of the table will increasingly take more time. Therefore it is prudent to use keys (primary, unique, indexes) that allows you to do binary search on your dataset and fetch data faster.

You will have to tune the queries as time goes. In most databases, there will be functionality to analyze your query. Such analysis can show bottlenecks such as table scan. Some database analysis tools can also recommend indexes.

For example:

```
create table employees1 (id int, fullname varchar(100))
vs.
create table employees2 (id int, fullname varchar(100), 
  primary key(id),
  key idx_employees_fullname(fullname))
```

As data increases in employees1 table, a query like `SELECT * from employees1 where fullname like 'John%'` will take increasingly long time. The same query run on employees2 will use an index (similar to what you have in the back of books) to quickly find all `John`s since the index knows which `id`s John is associated with.

Wisely create database structure and keys. Routinely analyze and tune database objects and queries. This is a loaded question with a lot of potential answers.